How can I right justify a text within a guizero TextBox?
By default, texts in a TexBox are left justified:     [Hello World....]
How do I make the text to be right justified?         [....Hello World]
Or center justified?                                  [..Hello World..]
I tried to use the .tk.justify = 'right' property to no avail.
Note that I'm not asking how to align the TexBox itself in an App or Widow widget.
Thanks
from guizero import App, TextBox

app = App()
t = TextBox(app, text="Hello World", width=15)
t.tk.justify = 'right' # Does nothing but no errors
app.display()


If the TextBox() is not ignoring leading whitespace, you may try sending an already justified string:
t = TextBox(app, text="%15s" % "Hello World", width=15)


You can use t._set_tk_config('justify', 'right'), although what the 'intended' way of doing it is, I can't say.
t._get_tk_config('justify') is 'left' by default
